# Do I have to cover pipes under slab?

Tags: plumbing, basement, pipe, drain-waste-vent, slab

I'm adding a new toilet in basement and would like to know if the (drain) pipes that will be buried under the slab have to be covered with something else exept of the gravel (like wrapping them or putting it in a larger diameter pipes) in order to protect it from the stress of the slab settling etc. When looking at the point of connection to the old pipes I see nothing.                                                   Thanks

Comment: Plumbing codes vary by region, so putting your location might be helpful, but generally you want to have some kind of sheathing or blocking where a line comes up through the slab, so that the concrete isn't right around the edge of the pipe. That can put a lot of stress on the piping.

Answer (score 3):

Normally your drain pipes are ABS plastic having them bedded in the rock is fine.
If your supply is copper (I do not recommend copper under a slab) it should be coated so the corrosive effects will not cause pin holes.
I have had to replace several sets of copper pipe under a slab it is very expensive the houses were not very old maybe 20 years.
I would use cpvc or maybe pex pipe under the slab. I love copper pipe but not in or under a slab.

Comment: Thanks @Ed Beal my question was only about drain ABS, I have the supply thru the walls.Thanks